# Как написать запрос where с несколькими параметрами?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id
```

где `:id` строка следующего вида "`2, 5, 7`"
Такой запрос конечно не сработает, ведь оператор ожидает всего один параметр и для моих хотелок нужен `AND`.

Может есть какой-то хак чтобы реализовать примерно такой же запрос, какой я описал выше?
Ведь моя строка может иметь больше 3 параметров.

Comment: `WHERE id IN (2, 5, 7)`

Comment: @andreymal то что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

если строки, как в вопросе, то
id in ('2','5','7')
если int, то без кавычек соотвественно